# How to create Backup of a mysql database in java

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, ubuntu

I have seen there are many articles on this issue and I tried all of them but I am still fail to create a backup using java.
Here is my code:

```
public class CreateBackup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("mysqlBackup");
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                file.mkdir();
            }
            String fileName = "backup_" + new Date().getTime() + ".sql";
            
            String path = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
            String cmd = "/usr/bin/mysqldump  -uroot -proot userDb > " + path; //-The root after u is the mysql database user name, and the 123456 followed by - p is the user password. Note that there is no space; dbName fills in the database name that needs to be backed up, and the greater than sign is followed by the generated file path
            System.out.println("path " +cmd);
            Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd );
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            /*NOTE: processComplete=0 if correctly executed, will contain other values if not*/
            if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup Complete");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Backup Failure");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to run in ubuntu also tried with windows but mentioning mysqldump full path "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump". Why my code is always returning backup failure? Help me, please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this code by adding more lines. while executing.

```
File f = new File(file, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime() + ".sql");
        String path = f.getPath();
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";
        String dbname = "userDb";
        String executeCmd = "/usr/bin/mysqldump -u" + username + " -p" + password
                + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbname + " -r " + path;
        Process runtimeProcess;
        try {
//            System.out.println(executeCmd);//this out put works in mysql shell
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            System.out.println(executeCmd);
//            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
            System.out.println("processComplete" + processComplete);
            if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup created successfully");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope it will help others..

Comment: Sir on my side, it is saying `Could not create backup` because the `processComplete` has value as `2`. There is no exception being displayed. Kindly help me.